# Animating transition from the last item of a list to the next item of another list with Viewpager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and a ViewPager2 on my page. There are several lists by type on this page. How can I design an animation that will make the viewPager transition smooth when I reach the last item of any of these lists and want to switch to the new list?

I have a RecyclerView and a ViewPager2 on my page. There are several lists by type on this page. How can I design an animation that will make the viewPager transition smooth when I reach the last item of any of these lists and want to switch to the new list

Comment: Please provide some code and edit your question correctly